# How to split a string by delimiter from the right?

Tags: scala

How to split a string by a delimiter from the right?

e.g.

```
scala> "hello there how are you?".rightSplit(" ", 1)
res0: Array[java.lang.String] = Array(hello there how are, you?)
```

Python has a `.rsplit()` method which is what I'm after in Scala:

```
In [1]: "hello there how are you?".rsplit(" ", 1)
Out[1]: ['hello there how are', 'you?']
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think the simplest solution is to search for the index position and then split based on that. For example:

```
scala> val msg = "hello there how are you?"
msg: String = hello there how are you?

scala> msg splitAt (msg lastIndexOf ' ')
res1: (String, String) = (hello there how are," you?")
```

And since someone remarked on `lastIndexOf` returning -1, that's perfectly fine with the solution:

```
scala> val msg = "AstringWithoutSpaces"
msg: String = AstringWithoutSpaces

scala> msg splitAt (msg lastIndexOf ' ')
res0: (String, String) = ("",AstringWithoutSpaces)
```

Comment: `lastIndexOf` can return `-1`.

Comment: @huynhjl In which case `splitAt` will return an empty string first, and the original string second.

Comment: Dang, you have thought of everything! You are right it works.

Comment: unlike the .rsplit() example above, this contains the delimiter, though

Answer (score 5):

You could use plain old regular expressions:

```
scala> val LastSpace = " (?=[^ ]+$)"
LastSpace: String = " (?=[^ ]+$)"

scala> "hello there how are you?".split(LastSpace)
res0: Array[String] = Array(hello there how are, you?)
```

`(?=[^ ]+$)` says that we'll look ahead (`?=`) for a group of non-space (`[^ ]`) characters with at least 1 character length. Finally this space followed by such sequence has to be at the end of the string: `$`.

This solution wont break if there is only one token:

```
scala> "hello".split(LastSpace)
res1: Array[String] = Array(hello)
```

Comment: I thought of suggesting a regular expression, but it's way less efficient and more difficult to understand than the simpler approach I ended up suggesting. Not to cast aspersions on your solution -- which is perfectly workable and different than the others presented --, but I wonder what it is about complex solutions that make people prefer them?

Answer (score 1):

```
scala> val sl = "hello there how are you?".split(" ").reverse.toList
sl: List[String] = List(you?, are, how, there, hello)

scala> val sr = (sl.head :: (sl.tail.reverse.mkString(" ") :: Nil)).reverse
sr: List[String] = List(hello there how are, you?)
```